# Earth invaded by alien entities feeding on electricity

Tags: story-identification, books, alien-invasion

I'm looking for a book that was purchased in the late '70s or early '80s.
The action takes place in the '60s to '70s.

Some day a radio amateur was puzzled by a strange Morse code message he received. This message came from nowhere, or, more precisely, his gonio showed it was coming down from the sky.

It turned out that this message was the first radio message ever broadcast by Marconi in 1897.

The guy kept monitoring this source, and he got more and more messages, which were all identified as known historical messages.

He kept getting more and more messages, the pace was accelerating, he got vocal messages, and within a few months he was overwhelmed by communication from WW2.

One day he identified messages dating a few hours back, and then the catastrophe occurred: anything electrical started to malfunction, and some time later the entire Earth suffered a total electrical blackout.

The Earth had been invaded by immaterial beings who were feeding on electricity and all kinds of electromagnetic waves.

Humanity had to return to the "good old times" with horse carriages, watermills, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Waveries](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44692) by Frederic Brown.

It starts with a dictionary definition:

> Definitions from the school-abridged Webster-Hamlin Dictionary 1998 edition: wavery (WA-ver-i) n. a vader-slang
>
> vader (VA-der) n. inorgan of the class Radio
>
> inorgan (in-OR-gan) n. noncorporeal ens, vader
>
> radio(RA-di-o) n.
>
> 1. class of inorgans
> 2. etheric frequency between light and electricity
> 3. (obsolete) method of communication used up to 1977

The story is exactly as you describe. The protagonist *George Bailey* detects a radio signal that is just a series of Morse code letter S's i.e dot-dot-dot. George is drunk and describes this as *Marconi* when he means *Morse*:

> George glanced at the radio. “Marconi,” he said.
> He meant Morse, naturally, but the whisky sours had muddled him a bit so his first guess was more nearly right than anyone else’s. It was Marconi, in a way. In a very peculiar way.

After that the story goes as you say. More and more transmissions are received until the Waveries arrive on Earth and make radio useless. But then electrically operated equipment stops working, and even lightning stops. It becomes apparent that the Waveries eat electricity and the story ends with Earth reverting to a pre-industrial lifestyle.

Comment: That's it )) Funny, but we also have electricity in our body, how can we survive? ))

Comment: Thank you, John ! That's it !

Comment: @pepilepioux I read it in the early 1970s when I was ten years old. It made a big enough impression on me that I can remember it fifty years later :-)

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi As you might expect, the author didn't delve into that in the story.  My own take would be that our nerve signals aren't really electric current, they're ionic in nature.  Hence why nerve impulses travel slower than sound (around 100 m/s, as I recall).

Comment: @ZeissIkon yes, we have that ionic current =) Probably not too interesting for wavers. But people with cardiostimulator would have no chance (
Also strange about steam power - author mentioned Diesel engines, so why use steam power? And main drawback - electrical currents in the Earth core. It that current goes, then magnetic field will go to, and so the protection against Solar wind... On the other hand - all those dangerous particles could be eaten by Waveries ) Funny )

Comment: On the other hand - why bother with electricity produced by mankind, if nature generates much more? Charged particles are directed to the poles, just go for them ) And Jupiter gathers much more of such particles (in case Waveries  can't eat charged particles directly from Sun or other star (as they could eat fast neutron and shut down nuclear plants).

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi As with many SF premises, this one doesn't stand up to too-close scrutiny.  And pacemakers etc. as we know them didn't exist (nor were really conceived of) when the story was written around 1945.

Comment: @ZeissIkon it was from 1945 )) cool